# What does $|N_G(P)|$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, notation

I am working on the same problem here: [A simple group of order $168$ doesn't have subgroups of order $14$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725227/a-simple-group-of-order-168-doesnt-have-subgroups-of-order-14)

I have prove most of the requirements, but I don't know what  $|N_G(P)|$ means, I haven't done it in my course yet. Can someone give the definition, a simple google could do it, thanks.

Comment: Cf. [normalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) of the subset $P$ in the group $G$

Comment: The cardinality (number of elements in) $N_G(P) = \{g\in G\mid gxg^{-1}\in P\text{ for all }x\in P\}$. Both the bar notation and $N_G(P)$ are pretty standard; it would be hard to work on questions about simple groups if you've never seen the normalizer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $S\subseteq G$, we denote by $\lvert S\rvert $ the cardinality of the set $S$.

The notation

$$N_G(P)=\{ g\in G\mid gP=Pg\}$$

is the [normaliser of $P\subseteq G$ in $G$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer), where

$$gP=\{ gp\in G\mid p\in P\}$$

and

$$Pg=\{ pg\in G\mid p\in P\}.$$